# Print an XML Element as XML text

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

## My Problem

I am parsing a large XML file from the FDA site using Python 3.8 native xml library. Since the file is large, I'm using the [`iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) function which reads one element at a time instead of loading the entire file to memory. I would like to print the XML text of the [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects), but could not find a way to do it.

## What Have I Tried

The usual suspects - RTFM, [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). However, I can only iterate into the children, but not print the item XML representation.

```py
for xml_filename in xml_filenames:
    for evt, elem in iterparse(xml_filename):
        if elem.tag == 'safetyreport':
            print(f'elem:     {elem}')           # elem:     <Element 'safetyreport' at 0x7fd77dc3b590>
            print(f'items:    {elem.items()}')   # items:    []
            print(f'type:     {type(elem)}') .   # type:     <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
            print(elem.getchildren())            # [<Element 'safetyreportversion' at 0x7fd77dc3fb80>, ...
```

## My Question

**How can I get the textual XML representation of an XML [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) in Python 3.8?**

Comment: Is it `tostring()` that you are looking for? https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring

Comment: No, it works on ElementTree, not on Element

Comment: I don't understand. `tostring()` is for generating a string representation of an `Element` object.

Comment: The Element is the first argument of `tostring()`. So you'd do something like: `print(ET.tostring(elem).decode())` (assuming the import `from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET`)

Comment: `iterparse` returns `Element`s, not `ElementTree`s - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The [tostring()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) function in ElementTree class generates the text representation of an XML element including all subelements.

**Example:**

```python
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml_filenames = [ ... ]

for xml_filename in xml_filenames:
    for evt, elem in ET.iterparse(xml_filename):
        if elem.tag == 'safetyreport':
            print(ET.tostring(elem, encoding='unicode')) # added line
```

**Sample input:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<collection>
  <safetyreport>
   <safetyreportversion>1</safetyreportversion>
   <safetyreportid>US-ABC-12345</safetyreportid>
  </safetyreport>
  <safetyreport>
   <safetyreportversion>1</safetyreportversion>
   <safetyreportid>US-XYZ-12346</safetyreportid>
  </safetyreport>  
</collection>
```

**Output:**

```
<safetyreport>
   <safetyreportversion>1</safetyreportversion>
   <safetyreportid>US-ABC-12345</safetyreportid>
  </safetyreport>

<safetyreport>
   <safetyreportversion>1</safetyreportversion>
   <safetyreportid>US-XYZ-12346</safetyreportid>
  </safetyreport>
```